OpenCLLink does print build errors (MacOS M1 / Wolfram Engine 14.1)
To reproduce an error
Needs["OpenCLLink`"]
OpenCLFunctionLoad["__kernel void kernel(__global float* in, __global float4* out) {}", "kernel", {{"Float", _, "Input"}, {"Float", _, "Output"}}, 256, "ShellOutputFunction"->Print]

>> OpenCLLink`Private`cGetProgramBuildLog[0,
"__kernel void kernel(__global float* in, __global float4* out) {}",
"-DUSING_OPENCL_FUNCTION=1 -DOPENCLLINK_USING_GENERIC -Dmint=int \
-DReal_t=double -DUSING_DOUBLE_PRECISIONQ=1"]

In a nutshell, it makes OpenCL development impossible

MacOS 14 Sonoma
M1 ARM
Wolfram Engine 14.1


To fix this we need to go deep into SystemFiles of Wolfram Kernel

Locate GPUTools private functions at app directory of Wolfram Kernel

../Contents/SystemFiles/Links/GPUTools/WGLPrivate.m


Find line 423

GetProgramBuildLog[id_Integer, source_String, buildOptions_String] :=
    Module[{res},
        res = cGetProgramBuildLog[id, source, buildOptions]; (* <---- *)
        If[SuccessQ[res],
            res,
            Throw[$Failed]
        ]
    ]

For some reason this function cGetProgramBuildLog was not loaded from the dynamic library file. I tried to guess arguments and import it using similar name, but C implementation differs it just does not work.
However! There is another one cGetProgramInformation, which can also fetch build information too. Looking at source code it is easy to guess that this patch
GetProgramBuildLog[id_Integer, source_String, buildOptions_String] :=
    Module[{res},
        (* res = cGetProgramBuildLog[id, source, buildOptions]; *)
        res = cGetProgramInformation[id, source, buildOptions, "BuildLog"];
        If[SuccessQ[res],
            res,
            Throw[$Failed]
        ]
    ]

Perfectly solves all issues.

Restart your Kernel and start again

Needs["OpenCLLink`"]
OpenCLFunctionLoad["__kernel void kernel(__global float* in, __global float4* out) {}", "kernel", {{"Float", _, "Input"}, {"Float", _, "Output"}}, 256, "ShellOutputFunction"->Print]

>> program_source:1:22: error: expected identifier or '('\n__kernel void \
kernel(__global float* in, __global float4* out) {}\n \
^\nprogram_source:1:22: error: expected ')'\nprogram_source:1:21: note: to \
match this '('\n__kernel void kernel(__global float* in, __global float4* \
out) {}\n ^\n
```


Unfortunately on my Windows 11 OpenCLLink does not work for many releases now. Nvidia cuda works... It just says https://i.imgur.com/c1FibAu.png

This is sad. That, what I have seen recently on one of my windows PC. I believe OpenCL was the only reliable and crossplatform choice, and not it is ruined too

Well, at least all CUDA stuff was fixed by Wolfram. It all works now with latest CUDA SDK. As I understand somehow OpenCL needs CUDA on Nvidia. If you reproduce this, I actually narrowed it down. There is an issue only in one file Get["OpenCLLink`OpenCLLink`"] in some of its dependencies. Your fix does not work.
